# dropdownlist with image mvc asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```html
   <select align="center" style="background-color:#ADCEEC;" name="webmenu" id="webmenu">
                        <option value="" title="~/Image/tb_viewer_fittopage_context.png">Auf Seite einpassen Alt+P</option>
                        <option value="" title="~/Image/tb_viewer_fittowidth_context.png">Auf Breite einpassen Alt+W</option>
                        <option value="" title="~/Image/tb_viewer_fittoheight_context.png">Auf Höhe einpassen Alt+H</option>
                        <option value="" selected="selected" title="~/Image/tb_viewer_onetoone_context.png">1:1</option>
                    </select>
```

I am using this plugin:
JavaScript image combobox v3.3
to have a dropdownlist with images..but is it possible to change it in a way that after clicking on each item only image becomes selected and displayed instead of both image and text together as a selected item.I want when I open the dropdown I see text and image both but after selection ,my selected item shows only related image.

best regards

this is how .css file looks like:

```html
.dd {
 /*display:inline-block !important;*/
 text-align:left;
 background-color:#fff;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
 float:left;
}
.dd .ddTitle {
 background:#f2f2f2;
 border:1px solid #c3c3c3;
 padding:3px;
 text-indent:0;
 cursor:default;
 overflow:hidden;
 height:16px;
}
.dd .ddTitle span.arrow {
 background:url(dd_arrow.gif) no-repeat 0 0; float:right; display:inline-block;width:16px; height:16px; cursor:pointer; 
}

.dd .ddTitle span.ddTitleText {text-indent:1px; overflow:hidden; line-height:16px;}
.dd .ddTitle span.ddTitleText img{text-align:left; padding:0 2px 0 0}
.dd .ddTitle img.selected {
 padding:0 3px 0 0;
 vertical-align:top;
}
.dd .ddChild {
 position:absolute;
 border:1px solid #c3c3c3;
 border-top:none;
 display:none;
 margin:0;
 width:auto;
 overflow:auto;
 overflow-x:hidden !important;
 background-color:#ffffff;    
}
.dd .ddChild .opta a, .dd .ddChild .opta a:visited {padding-left:10px}
.dd .ddChild a {
 display:block;
 padding:2px 0 2px 3px;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#000;
 overflow:hidden;
 white-space:nowrap;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.dd .ddChild a:hover {
 /*background-color:#66CCFF;*/
    background-color:lightgray;
}
.dd .ddChild a img {
 border:0;
 padding:0 2px 0 0;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
.dd .ddChild a.selected {
 /*background-color:#66CCFF;*/
 background-color:#ADCEEC;
}
.hidden {display:none;}

.dd .borderTop{border-top:1px solid #c3c3c3 !important;}
.dd .noBorderTop{border-top:none 0  !important}
```

this is how .css file looks like:

and this is what I added to my razor view:

and finally what I added as javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function (e) {
         try {
          $("body select").msDropDown();
       } catch (e) {
          alert(e.message);
       }
});
```

it's the image of how dropdown looks like:
[image: it seems that it takes space for both image and text no matter I select only image or I select both image and text]

Comment: without looking at it I'd guess there is some CSS involved in displaying the image. If you examine how the markup is built, you could probably override the CSS to hide the image part of it.

Comment: Still I don't know how to change it....I changed the css file a bit but nothing has changed....

Comment: well, without seeing what you've done it's impossible say why it doesn't work. You should be able to use the Snippets feature on this site as part of the question to create an example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I added .css file and my razor view to question....the thing is that I don't know how to change css to achieve what I wanted....I tried to change .css file but because I am very new in .css I couldn't change the related part.Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the sample here: http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/examples/index.html It looks like the options are built using a list, rather than the standard `<option>` tags. For the image there is simply an`<img` tag inserted into the markup. e.g. one option looks like:

```
<li> class="enabled _msddli_">
 <img src="..images/msdropdown/icons/Amex-56.png">
  <span class="ddlalbel">Amex</span>
  <span class="description">My life. My card...<span>
  <div class="clear"><div>
</li>
```

So you would have to hide everything except the `<img` tag. I think you can simply write a CSS rule like this:

```
.ddTitleText > span 
{ 
  display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I faced another problem....is it possible to change width of dropdown in a way that I have a small space just to show selected image but when I open dropdown I have enough space for image and text both....because now when I change the width of <select> to smaller size ,after I open dropdown the text is somehow disappeared......I will attach an image to my main question.....it has taken a large space which does not look good.

Comment: Hi. I answered the question as originally asked. If you have another problem please ask a new question. If you link to it here I will take a look. Otherwise your revised question and my answer do not make sense to future readers.

Comment: ahaa...sorry......I asked a new question..this is the link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591862/changing-the-width-of-javascript-image-combobox-v3-3-when-we-only-select-image