# changing the width of JavaScript image combobox v3.3 when we only select image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

recently,T faced a problem in changing the width of JavaScript image combobox v3.3....is it possible to change width of dropdown in a way that I can have a small space just to show selected image but when I open dropdown I have enough space for image and text both....because now when I change the width of  to smaller size ,after I open dropdown the text is somehow disappeared......I will attach an image to my main question.....it has taken a large space which does not look good[image]

regards

Comment: Could anyone find a solution?....